# Systems of Congruences Modulo a Prime

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be prime and $A,B\subseteq\{{1,\dots,p}\}$ be distinct s.t. $|A|=|B|=\left\lfloor p/2\right\rfloor$ and suppose I have a system of $k$ congruences $$\sum_{i\in A}i^d \equiv \sum _{j\in B}j^d\mod p$$ for $1\leq d\leq k$.  Equivalently, by removing $A\cap B$, we have $$\sum_{i\in A\backslash B}i^d \equiv \sum _{j\in B\backslash A}j^d\mod p$$

Is it possible for  $|A\backslash B|\leq k$ and $|B\backslash A|\leq k$? Supposing it is, does the second set of congruences imply that $A \backslash B=B\backslash A$ and is therefore empty.  This would, of course, imply $A=B$, a contradiction.

Comment: What are "the former" and "the latter" respectively?

Comment: Sorry if that was vague.  The former conclusion is that at least one $i\in A$ is equal to some $j \in B$, while the latter is that $A=B$.

Comment: It is not vague; it lacks completes the latter! There is no appearance at all of $A=B$ in the question, isn't it? In any case, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @BrentMcKain, you should perhaps rewrite the question to be more clear.

Comment: When do you ask whether $A$ and $B$ must have common elements, do you mean mod $p$? Perhaps is it better that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\Bbb Z_p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $A,B$ are both subsets of e.g. $\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$, we have equality:
The elements $a_1,\ldots, a_k$ of $A$ are roots of $(X-a_1)(X-a_2)\cdot\ldots\cdot (X-a_k)$, a polynomial of degree $k$. We can do the same for $B$. The coefficients of this polynomial are the elementary symmetric polynomials in the roots and one can express these in terms of the symmetric polynomials $\sum_i a_i^d$ (because wlog. $k< p$). By the given equalities we conclude that $B$ leads to the same polynomial (modulo $p$), hence $A=B$.

Normally one works the other way round, i.e., one uses the result that any symmetric polynomial can be expressed using the elementary symmetric polynomals $\sigma_1=a_1+\ldots +a_k$, $\sigma_2=a_1a_2+a_1a_3+\ldots +a_{k-1}a_k$, $\ldots$, $\sigma_k=a_1a_2\cdots a_k$. That the converse holds for the cases used here, requires some consideration:
To begin with, $\sum a_i^1=\sigma_1$ is by itself an elementary symmetric polynomial.
Assume we have expressed all elementary symmetric polynomials of degree $\le n-1$ in terms of the $\sum a_i^d$ with $d\le n-1$. Now we attempt to do the same with the degree $n$ elementary symmetric polynomial (where $n\le k<p$).
When we express $\sum a_i^n$ as polynomial in $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_k$ (or in fact only $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$) then $(-1)^nn\sigma_n$ is one of the monomials. This follows because for the (e.g., complex) polynomial $X^k-X^{k-n}=(X^n-1)X^{k-n}$ we have $\sigma_1=\ldots=\sigma_{n-1}=0$ and $\sigma_n=(-1)^n$ and of course the sum of $n$th powers of its roots is $n$. Since $n$ is invertible modulo $p$, we can solve for $\sigma_n$ in terms of $\sum a_i^n$ and the lower degree symmetric polynomials, hence by induction in terms of the $\sum a_i^d$, $d\le n$.

Comment: That did the trick!